# Problem with MySQL and UTF-8

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems when configuring a server with UTF8. Well, I'm not configuring it exactly. I client from where I work does and I think that he's not an expert configuring web servers.

My PHP+MySQL application needs to use Apache and MySQL in UTF8. After various e-mails, this person configured apache with utf8 support but now it's time to MySQL and there is no way we can configure it. I don't know what to do because I'm not a system administrator but I configured apache/mysql on ubuntu with utf8 support looking into Google.

What I said to him is that please, use the next configuration on **my.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-filesystem=UTF8
character-set-server=UTF8
default-collation=UTF8_general_ci
default-character-set=UTF8

[client]
default-character-set=UTF8

[mysqldump]
default-character-set=UTF8
```

But nothing changed. He passed me the my.cnf that is running, you can see it here: http://pastebin.com/NfcgKKiM ... and doesn't works the UTF8 encoding on MySQL.

What I did in PHP is launch a MySQL query every time with `SET NAMES`utf8`` and it works as UTF8 but I don't think that is the best option but proves that something is miss configured. No?

What I can do? What I can say to the server admin?

Thank you and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What "CHARACTER SET" and "COLLATE" in DB(show create database DB_NAME)?

Try:

```
[mysqld]
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple more parameters in your `my.cnf`, here's what it looks like in mine

```
[client] 
default-character-set=utf8 

[mysql] 
default-character-set=utf8 

[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
default_character_set=utf8
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci
```

This should give you full UTF8 support on the MySQL backend

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your tables have the correct character set in MySQL
- Use UTF-8 content encoding on all pages
- Set your MySQL session character set to UTF-8

All my pages begin like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

My MySQL connection looks like this: (note the `PDO::exec()` call)

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO(('mysql:host=' . $mbdbhost . ';dbname=' . $mbdbname), $mbdbuser, $mbdbpass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
  $dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  header("Location: error.php");
}
```

My tables look a bit like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fotouser (
  idfotouser INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  person INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (idfotouser) ,
  INDEX person (person ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT person
   FOREIGN KEY (person)
   REFERENCES mb_person (idmb_person)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_swedish_ci ;
```